# Systemd Service/Timer -- Oneshot service w/ timer executes multiple times and failed w/ 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: systemd

I want to start a command (unison) every 5 min as a systemd.service via a systemd.timer unit.   The '.service' file alone runs fine. However when it's started by the timer unit, it runs multiple times and stops with these errors: `Start request repeated too quickly.` and `Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'`.  But why?

I start the timer service like this: `systemctl --user start service.timer`.

The files are located in: `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/`.

**sync.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/zsh -l -c "unison -batch %u"
ExecStartPost=/bin/zsh -l -c 'dunstify "sync ~"'

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**sync.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for Sync Service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:0/5:*
AccuracySec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The unison command syncs over the network into a server via ssh with a password proteceted keyfile.  A `ssh-agent` instance is running by the user.  That's why i have to use a login shell: `zsh -l -c "..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: `OnCalendar=*-*-* *:0/5:*` is simply wrong. `OnCalendar=*-*-* *:0/5:00` does stoping the multiple execution.